# Questions about time series and overfitting and underfitting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, lstm

When we want to compare between loss and val_loss, do we only care about the last epochs? Do the following charts show that the model is not overfitted nor underfitted? Can you please give me comments and interpretations about the 4 charts? This will really help me learn.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is a regression time series problem, nearly 300 records for training and each record representing a different day, is that enough to use LSTM?

Thanks in advance.